# Process.start() in a loop doesn't maintain FIFO

Tags: c#, .net

I want to print pdf files in a foreach loop which doesn't maintain FIFO. Applied even lock and semaphore using concurrent queue. But, sometimes misses the sequence. How can I make printing process maintaining confirm FIFO and Thread-safe?  My code is as follows,

```
foreach(string pfile in printdoc)
{
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
    info.Verb = "print";
    info.CreateNoWindow = true;
    info.FileName = pfile;
    info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo = info;
    p.Start();
}
```

Comment: You'd need to serialize them to ensure FIFO, that is wait for process 5 to complete before starting process 6.  Otherwise different runtimes (to render and print) will shuffle to order.

Comment: Could you please mention any link or exemple for such an exemple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the previous one to finish before you start the next itteration. Throw a `p.WaitForExit()` on the end to wait for the print to finish before queuing the next one.

```
foreach(string pfile in printdoc)
{
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
    info.Verb = "print";
    info.CreateNoWindow = true;
    info.FileName = pfile;
    info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

    //You can shorten your existing code to a single line using Process.Start(
    Process p = Process.Start(info);
    p.WaitForExit();
}
```

For thread safety it depends on what kind of collection `printdoc` is, the easiest solution is to use a `BlockingCollection<string>` and make your foreach in to `foreach(string pfile in printdoc.GetConsumingEnumerable())`

Comment: Used BlockingCollection<string> and GetConsumingEnumerable() in foreach but still can't maintain the queue. Any other suggestions?

Comment: The WaitForExit is the important part.

Comment: WaitForExit() didn't help actually, but Thread.sleep(5000) helped instead, but a bit concern whether it can confirm maintaining in case of different document size.